# Are asyncio's EventLoop tasks created with loop.create_task a FIFO

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I can not find any documentation on this, but empirically it *seems* that it is.

In what order will the coroutines 1 and 2 run in the following three examples and is the order always guaranteed?

**A**

```
loop.run_until_complete(coro1)
loop.run_until_complete(coro2)
loop.run_forever()
```

**B**

```
loop.create_task(coro1)
loop.create_task(coro2)
loop.run_forever()
```

**C**

```
loop.create_task(coro1)
loop.run_until_complete(coro2)
loop.run_forever()
```

etc.

Comment: Your question is too broad.
Short answer is: no, they are not identical. Waiting for coroutine finishing is not equal to starting a new async task.

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov OK. will rephrase to be more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, `coro1` will run until it is complete. Then `coro2` will run. This is essentially the same as if they were both synchronous functions.

In your second example, `coro1` will run until it's told to await. At that point control is yielded to `coro2`. `coro2` will run until it's told to await. At that point the loop will check to see if `coro1` is ready to resume. This will repeat until both are finished and then the loop will just wait.

In your final example, `coro2` starts first, following the same back and forth as the previous example, and then the process will stop once it, `coro2`, is done. Then `coro1` will resume until it's done and then the loop will just wait.

A fourth example is

```
loop.run_until_complete(
    asyncio.gather(
        asyncio.ensure_future(coro1),
        asyncio.ensure_future(coro2),
    )
)
```

It will behave like the second example except it will stop once both are complete.